# c++ if statement not working in overloaded "++" postfix operator

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm trying to have the overloaded postfix operator make day = 1 whenever its day 365 the first snipped is me creating the prototype, and the second snippet is the actual code definition, i can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.
basically the program asks the user what day of the year do they want the date for.

so the day could be 364 which would be December 30.

I want the ++ operator to bring the day back to day 1 whenever I use it to increment objects that's day is 365. If the object isn't 365 I just want it to increment by 1 day

whenever I change it to if(day == 365)
 it does the same thing, it still increments by one, but I end up with 366, not 1.

I appreciate the help. It's a homework assignment, but it has me stomped. 
EDIT : Posted more code. Thanks again for the help guys

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class DayOfYear {            
    public:
        DayOfYear(int d);
        void print();
        static string month;
        DayOfYear();
        DayOfYear(string m, int d);
        DayOfYear operator++(int);
        int day;    
};

string DayOfYear::month;

DayOfYear DayOfYear::operator++(int) {
    DayOfYear temp = *this;    

    if (day == 365) {
        day = 1;
    } else {
        day++;
    }

    return temp;
}

DayOfYear::DayOfYear(string m, int d) {
    month = m;
    day = d;

    if (m == "January" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "February" && d > 28) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "March" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "April" && d > 30) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "May" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "June" && d > 30) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "July" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "August" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "September" && d > 30) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "October" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "November" && d > 30) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    } else if (m == "December" && d > 31) {
        cout << "ERROR INVALID DATE: PROGRAM TERMINATING!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    cout << month << " " << day << endl; 
}

DayOfYear::DayOfYear() {
    cout << "Enter a day number." << endl;
    cin >> day;
    print();
}

DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int d) {
    day = d;

    while (d > 365 || d < 1) {
        cout << "Day can't be higher than 365 and must be at least one. " << endl;
        cin >> d; 
        day = d; 
    }

    print();
}

void DayOfYear::print() {
    if (day > 0 && day < 32) //jan 31 
    {
        month = "January";
        cout << month << " " << 31 + day - 31 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 31 && day < 60) // feb 28
    {
        month = "February";
        cout << month << " " << day - 31  << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 59 && day < 91) // march 31
    {
        month = "March";
        cout << month << " " << day - 59 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 90 && day < 121) // april 30 
    {
        month = "April";
        cout << month << " " << day - 90 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 120 && day < 152) //may 31
    {
        month = "May";
        cout << month << " " << day - 120 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 151 && day < 182) //june 30
    {
        month = "June";
        cout << month << " " << day - 151 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 181 && day < 213) //july 31
    {
        month = "July";
        cout << month << " " << day - 181 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 212 && day < 244) // august 31
    {
        month = "August";
        cout << month << " " << day - 212 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 243 && day < 274) // sept 30
    {
        month = "September";
        cout << month << " " << day - 243 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 273 && day < 305) // oct 31
    {
        month = "October";
        cout << month << " " << day - 273 << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 304 && day < 335) // nov 30
    {
        month = "November";
        cout << month << " " << day - 304  << endl;
    }
    else if (day > 334 && day < 366) //dec 31
    {
        month = "December";
        cout << month << " " << day - 334 << endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    DayOfYear day;

    cout << day.day << endl; 
    cout << day.day ++ << endl;
    cout << day.day << endl;

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: `day = 365` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `day=365` assigns the value `365` to the field `day`. If you want to compare, use `==`.

Comment: This can be prevented by using "Yoda Conditions" (constant value first): `if (365 == day) ...`.

Comment: If you're claiming that `==` does the same thing, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can reasonably figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, Except that those are hard to read and any decent compiler will warn you.

Comment: even when I change it to == it doesn't change a thing

Comment: Also make sure that you know the difference between `operator++(int)` and `operator++()`.

Comment: @bigdog225 Then there is *another* problem. Please fix the assignment vs comparison issue and then we can work from there.

Comment: To prove my point about an SSCCE, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7e14ebee0a65e8fdbb52b04c60e768cb-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f

Comment: @bigdog225 Note you can simplify it to just `if(++day > 365) day = 1;`

Comment: Or `day = day%365 + 1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling your overloaded `operator++` anywhere.

```
DayOfYear day;
cout << day.day << endl; 
cout << day.day ++ << endl;
cout << day.day << endl;
```

`day.day` is the member `day` of the `DayOfYear` class, so `day.day++` is just an ordinary increment of an `int`. You want to do this instead:

```
DayOfYear day;
cout << day.day << endl; 
cout << (day++).day << endl;
cout << day.day << endl;
```

Comment: thanks Magtheridon96 and Oktalist,your help is very much appreciated, and thanks to everyone else who tried to help me as well!

Answer (score 5):

```
if(day = 365)
{day = 1;}
else
{day ++;}
```

This does not do what you think. `=` is the assignment operator. `==` would be the comparison operator. Currently, that expression is assigning the value `365` to the `day` variable and it's returning `365`, which executes `day = 1;` (Anything that is not `0` is `true`)

This is what you want to do:

```
if (day == 365) {
    day = 1;
} else {
    day++;
}
```

---

The problem with your code is that although you are defining the post-fix `operator++` for the class, you're using this operator on the `int day` member of the class.

In `int main`, you shouldn't be doing `day.day++`, you should be doing `day++`.

Comment: DayOfYear temp = *this;    
    if(day == 365)
    {day = 1;}
    else
    {day ++;}
    return temp;

Comment: I get the same result. I've tried that. Thanks for helping me though. I'm not trying to be it a know it all, if I seem to come off that way.

Comment: Do note that you shouldn't be taking an `int` argument for this function

Comment: it tells me to take an (int) argument in my textbook that the compiler knows that its a postfix ++ instead of prefix --. The book call it a dummy parameter

Comment: @bigdog225, It's right, but you *should* implement the prefix increment operator as well. After that, the postfix increment operator can simply be `ClassName operator++(int) {auto temp{*this}; ++temp; return temp;}`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, apologies for that mistake.

Comment: @magtheridon96 its cool man. so after i create the prefix operator, it should work just fine?

Comment: @bigdog225, It should work fine as is.

Comment: it doesn't, and im not sure why, and in main im printing the object when it first starts, then when it uses the increment operator, and then one step after the increment operator

Comment: it prints 365, 365 when it hits increment, and when its by itself it goes to 366

Comment: At this point, I think it's time to post more code in the question :|

Comment: ok If it's ok, im going to post the whole code guys

Comment: I have cleaned up your code in the post and the error has been identified. You aren't actually using operator++ of the class, you're doing it for the integer :v